# Disable ORMLite logs when using log4j 2.13

Tags: java, logging, log4j, ormlite

I am using log4j:2.13 and ORMLite:5.1

I cannot figure out how to disable (or change level) of ORMLite logs without affecting the level of logs on the rest of my application.

ORMLite's documenation states that I should do the following:
`log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite=DEBUG` [(source)](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Logging)

Well this doesn't seem to work. I am new to using log4j. Does anyone know the solution?

Here is my `log4j2.properties` file:

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

# Even if I set this to ERROR, log4j continues logging at debug level because I set it above..
log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite.level = ERROR
```

No matter what log level I try, it seems that `rootLogger.level` takes priority and "overrides" the ormlite setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often such problem is caused by the fact that there is more than one Log4J config file in the class path. The first found config is used. Some other file could have been found earlier than yours.

What can you do? Analyze you class path, all JARs in the class path, all directories (if any) in the class path. If in doubt, check in debugger what config file was used.

**Update**

The line with `log4j.logger` is not correct. Change it as follows (set other logger name if you wish):

```
logger.ormlite.name = com.j256.ormlite
logger.ormlite.level = error
```

Comment: Hmm.. My concern with what you said is that I am sure that my config file is used. The log format is the one I specified and if I change the `rootLogger.level` I get the expected results. My only issue is that I cannot separate the `ormlite` logging level from the general logging level.

Comment: @TheCrafter: OK, so we have localized the problem. Since we know this is the active config, now check the properties. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm! I suspected that the format was wrong but I couldn't find what is the correct one. Thank you for your help. I will send an email to the guys that created OMRLite to inform them to update that part of their documentation :)

Comment: @TheCrafter: Many libraries change over the time. Also the Log4j hash changed.